# Cordova 3.0.0 - How to install a plugin

Tags: plugins, cordova

I'm totally new to app development and just started to make my first steps.
I've installed Cordova and the needed utilities according [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) guide.

I've created my first app (using Cordova's create script) and I'm able to run it on my Nexus 4.
Now I tried to install a plugin using plugman, and I'm stuck.
This [tutorial](http://cordova.apache.org/blog/releases/2013/07/23/cordova-3.html) says I can install a plugin using

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```

in the application directory.
Two issues here:
1. In the application directory itself isn't a executable file named "cordova"
2. When I swtich to the cordova directory and execute the mentioned command, I get this error:

> Cordova does not recognize the command plugin

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or is ther a mistake in the tutorial?
Thanks a lot for any help!

EDIT:
I managed to install the plugins using plugman directly using

> plugman install --platform android --project . --plugin
>   https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git

But nevertheless I'm still interested in how to install the plugins using cordova...

Comment: Been a while for this question but maybe you didn't install cordova cli `npm install -g cordova`

Answer (score 24):

Below are several ways I've used to install plugins from Cordova CLI, hope it helps:

Firstly, make sure you've installed cordova correctly(please refer to [official document](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) if needed):

```
cordova -v   // should print something like "3.5.0-0.2.6"
```

1. Install from Cordova plugin registry

   `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device`

   This should cover most cases and here is a list of [plugins available in Cordova Plugin Registry](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/viewAll).
2. Install from a remote repository, typically from GitHub
   `cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin`

   If you encountered something like "Error: Command failed: error: Failed connect to help.github.com:443; Connection refused while accessing", typically it's a proxy issue, you could retry after config your proxy:

   `git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy:xxx`

   If it still not works, you could click "Dowload Zip" from github, unzip the downloaded file and then:
3. Install from a local directory

   `cordova plugin add /path/to/directory`

   It will look in this directory and each of its subdirectories for the plugin.

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE: this is related to Android platform of cordova 3.4 on my windows 8 machine (tested)**

step 1=> Install plugman by command in cmd   "npm install -g plugman" (note that you must have node installed)

step 2=> Download git from http://msysgit.github.com/ for windows (15 mb) install exe file

step 3=> create new variable in enviorment variable name = GIT_PATH and value= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git (this is mine urs may be diff)", now append %GIT_PATH% in Path variable (very Important) check git command in cmd if no error than continue otherwise fix this now

step 4=> Now go to http://plugins.cordova.io/#/ find whatever plugin want to install. and get just this repository url like

step 5=> now whatever and anywhere project is, place following command in cmd

```
**plugman install --platform android --project F:\my17app\ --plugin https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git**
```

Step 7=> If it successfully install we can see in app/res/xml/config.xml file a new feature will be added with id of new plugin

```
PS: For environment variables see in control Panel=> System and Security => System =>Advanced System Security
```

Comment: PS! Also found that I needed to go a bit deeper in my app... for example: F:\my17app\platforms\android

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this manner

```
D:\phonegap\hello>plugman install --platform android --project D:\phonegap\hello
\platforms\android --plugin org.apache.cordova.battery-status
```

where as for doing it from git

```
    plugman install --platform android --project D:\phonegap\hello
\platforms\android --plugin https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
```